# Pascal IDE output problem

Tags: command-line, 16.04, pascal

I have a problem when i run a program in pascal the output text is not formated right, it should write the text at the bottom of the terminal but instead it writes it over the existing text in the top left corner.

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

It should be like this:

[image: Correct output]

Comment: If someone has this problem, i fixed it with installing other terminal emulator.  MATE Terminal